# Significado de "bastiniano"

Tags: significado, cuba

Tengo que traducir al inglés la palabra "bastiniano", pero me está costando bastante entenderla! Os pido ayuda en comprender este tema.

Aquí está un extracto del texto en el cual se encuentra la palabra:

> Yo me levanté de madrugada, fui para la casa de Carlos 
>   y llamé varias veces frente a la ventana de su cuarto, 
>   pero Carlos no respondió; evidentemente, no quería 
>   responder. Pero como yo ya estaba dispuesto a dejarlo 
>   todo, eché a caminar rumbo a Velasco; me pasé un día 
>   caminando hasta que llegué al pueblo. Pensé que allí 
>   me iba a encontrar con muchos rebeldes que me iban a 
>   aceptar con júbilo, pero en Velasco no había rebeldes ni 
>   tampoco soldados **bastinianos**; había un pueblo que se 
>   moría de hambre, compuesto en su mayoría por mujeres. Yo solo tenía cuarenta y siete centavos.

Lo que ya tengo claro, es que estos soldados no son rebeldes. Entonces, me pregunto si son soldados del estado?

¿Qué es lo que entendéis por esta palabra?

**La fuente del texto es "Un rebelde con causa" de Reinaldo Arenas. Se trata de Cuba.**

Comment: Quiza puedas traducirlo como **bastinian soldier** basandote en la similitud de que un _soldado palestino_ es un **palestinian soldier**??.

Comment: @JMB entonces solo se trata de un error como dice rsanchez en su respuesta, la manera correcta es **batistianos** que eran los leales a [Batista](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgencio_Batista)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*bastiniano* se encuentra en algunos lugares como refiriéndose al régimen de Fulgencio Batista, el dictador que gobernó Cuba hasta la revolución de 1959. Los soldados bastinianos serían soldados leales a Batista. Probablemente provenga de un error de tipeo o confusión al escribir [*batistiano*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/batistiano), que sería la manera correcta de escribirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @rsanchez en su respuesta, debe haber algun tipo de error de tipeo para referirse a **batistianos** que eran los soldados o personas leales al gobierno de [Fulgencio Batista](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgencio_Batista)

En internet he econtrado varias referencias y lo mismo lo usan sin traducir como traducido al ingles al referirse a los batistianos.

Sin traducir:

> [Batistianos executed in Santa Clara, Jan. 2, 1959](http://www.latinamericanstudies.org/revolutionary-firing-squads-1.htm)

Traducido:

> [Batista's soldiers executing a rebel by firing squad in 1956](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulgencio_Batista#mediaviewer/File:BatistaFireSquad.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo el texto yo interpreto que en le pueblo de Velasco podia haber o bien soldados rebeldes o soldados

a) de un pueblo, ciudad o region llamada Bastian.

b) leales a un individuo llamado Bastian.